# How to use angularJs in GWT?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gwt

I want to integrate angularJs in my existing GWT application. I am new to angularJs. How to start with it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at

**[AngularGWT](https://github.com/cromwellian/angulargwt)**  - This is a library that enables Authors to write components or complete apps for AngularJS in Java. This is mostly done using compiler castings for Google Web Toolkit to "compile" Java Code into Javascript.

Answer (score 4):

**AngularGWT** is the way to go. But if you want an simple way off, **include the angular.js in your *.html** file and use JSNI to access Angular JS from your code.